# What are the ways to measure the power consumption of audio in mobile devices？

Tags: audio, profiling

I would like to collect what measures are available in terms of audio power consumption to help me do my job.

what tools are available？

At the moment I know of the tools are:

1. sysMonAPP profiling
2. QACT profiling
3. hansei.py --- LPASS vote
4. Power consumption disassembly
5. ...

I'd like to see several open source tools for analyzing audio power issues